# Как опубликовать сайт на java сервлетах?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, tomcat

Есть проект(maven) на java-сервлетах, написан в idea. Локально работает через томкат. Проект учебный, хотелось бы его залить на домен бесплатный, чтобы демонстрировать не с локального ПК, а с домена. Посоветуйте куда и как, ни разу не делал этого) Спасибо!

Comment: могу посоветовать читать про vps

Comment: Гугл вот такую статью на хабре выдаёт: https://habrahabr.ru/post/145203/

Comment: можешь почитать про heroku

Comment: есть вариант показать свое приложение не заливая его никуда. но при этом у приложения будет глобальный адрес, который можно будет дать другим людям. такое решение подходит?

Comment: @Mikhail Vaysman, DinDNS+домашняя машина? В любом случае я бы послушал )

Comment: @Tachkin тогда вам надо задать другой вопрос или переделать этот.